# Convert tree file to Table format using bash

Tags: bash, database-design, tree, type-conversion, bioinformatics

I have this input(input.txt):

> (((((((hg38:0.00390111,panTro4:0.00466345):0.0067608,ponAbe2:0.0116062):0.00867419,((((rheMac3:0.00199139,macFas5:0.00136397):0.00219754,papAnu2:0.00373049):0.00221139,chlSab2:0.00690005):0.00434788,(nasLar1:0.00415921,rhiRox1:0.00361872):0.0075705):0.0149329):0.0129667,(calJac3:0.025809,saiBol1:0.0245054):0.0316131):0.0521649,tarSyr2:0.113368):0.00737652,(micMur1:0.0695349,otoGar3:0.105996):0.0356137):0.00510281,mm10:0.304925);

I'm trying to convert it to a table format using this code and adding "branch" when a number is not preceded by a species (hg38, panTro4, ponAbe2,rheMac3, macFas5,papAnu2, chSab2, nasLar1, rhiRox1, calJac3, saiBol1, tarSyr2, micMur1, otoGar3, mm10)

```
cat input.txt | tr ',' '\n' | tr ':' '\t' | tr -d '()' |
awk -F '\t' '{if (NF == 1) {printf "%s\t%s\n", "branch", $1} else {printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $2}}'
```

However I'm getting this output:

```
branch  hg380.00390111 
branch  panTro40.004663450.0067608 
branch  ponAbe20.01160620.00867419 
branch  rheMac30.00199139 
branch  macFas50.001363970.00219754 
branch  papAnu20.003730490.00221139 
branch  chlSab20.006900050.00434788 
branch  nasLar10.00415921 
branch  rhiRox10.003618720.00757050.01493290.0129667 
branch  calJac30.025809 
branch  saiBol10.02450540.03161310.0521649 
branch  tarSyr20.1133680.00737652 
branch  micMur10.0695349 
branch  otoGar30.1059960.03561370.00510281 
branch  mm100.304925
```

For instance, in this part:
(((((((hg38:0.00390111,panTro4:0.00466345):0.0067608...

The 0.0067608 should be under the value of panTro4, and dubbed as  in the output but it should be under which I call hag38-panTro4. The same should happen with the other branches
This is the desired format output in a tab delimited table:

```
hg38    0.00390111
panTro4 0.00466345
hg38-panTro4    0.0067608 
ponAbe2 0.0116062
hg38-ponAbe2    0.00867419 
rheMac3 0.00199139 
macFas5 0.00136397
rheMac3-macFas5 0.00219754 
papAnu2 0.00373049
rheMac3-papAnu2 0.00221139 
chlSab2 0.00690005
rheMac3-chlSab2 0.00434788 
nasLar1 0.00415921 
rhiRox1 0.00361872
nasLar1-rhiRox1 0.0075705
rheMac3-nasLar1 0.0149329
hg38-rheMac3    0.0129667 
calJac3 0.025809 
saiBol1 0.0245054
calJac3-saiBol1 0.0316131
hg38-calJac3    0.0521649 
tarSyr2 0.113368
hg38-tarSyr2    0.00737652 
micMur1 0.0695349 
otoGar3 0.105996
micMur1-otoGar3 0.0356137
hg38-micMur1    0.00510281 
mm10    0.304925
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, image changed

Comment: I think you want your first test to be `if (NR == 1)` . Also confirm you don't have Windows Line endings in your data with `cat -vet myFile` . If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then use `dos2unix myFile`.  AND I only get 15 records from your input being processed up to the last `tr -d '()'`. Good luck.

Comment: How does your input produce the desired output?  I.e. what is the algorithm to go from one to the other?  Present your input data in such a way as we can understand that algorithm (so not all on one line with a bunch of `()`) and propose some ways to code it.  I tried to format it and the the parenthesis are not balanced.  You have more ) and (.

Comment: @Nic3500 I edited the post. Is it working now the input for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions/understandings:

- each line of input is a new 'tree' (aka a new table)
- each line of input is guaranteed to have a matching number of left and right parens
- each line of input contains *no* white space (ie, no spaces, no tabs)
- a species only occurs once in a line otherwise this answer may not generate the desired output
- OP has access to `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`) so that we can make use of the 4th argument to the `split()` function

General approach:

- ouput format will be *a)* `<species>   <nbr>` or *b)* `<species>-<branch>   <nbr>`
- we'll use a pair of stacks (implemented as arrays `spec[]` and `branch[]`) to keep track of our species and branches; `s` and `b` will be our array indices, respectively
- split a line on multiple delimiters `(`, `)` and `,`; this will leave us with fields of the format *a)* `<species>:<nbr>` or *b)* `:<nbr>` or *c)* `<empty>`
- if a field has the format `<species>:<nbr>` then we print `<species>  <nbr>` to stdout and then look at the previous delimiter ...
- if the previous delimiter was a `(` then we push `<species>` onto both arrays otherwise we only push `<species>` onto the `branch[]` array
- if a field has the format `:<nbr>` then we print `<species>-<branch>  <nbr>` (ie, current top of the two stacks/arrays == `spec[s]-branch[b]`) and then pop the current entry from the branch stack (ie, `b--`); however, there is one exception to this step ...
- if the top of both stacks is the same species (ie, `spec[s] == branch[b]`) then we first pop the top off the species stack (ie, `s--`) before performing the previous print and pop-of-the-branch-stack

One `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`) approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { delete spec                                  # init stack/array
        delete branch                                # init stack/array
        s=b=0                                        # init array indices
        print "########### new table"
        n=split($0,arr,"[(),]",seps)                 # split current line on triple delimiters, fields go into array arr[] while delimiters go into array seps[]

        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {                         # loop through our fields
            split(arr[i],x,":")                      # split current field into two pieces: x[1]/species and x[2]/nbr

            if (! arr[i])                            # if current field is empty then skip to next field
               continue
            else
            if (! x[1]) {                            # if species is empty => field looks like ":<nbr" then ...
               if (spec[s]==branch[b]) s--           # if top of both stacks is the same then pop the species stack
               print spec[s] "-" branch[b], x[2]     # print our species-branch/nbr and ...
               b--                                   # pop the branch stack
            }
            else
            if (seps[i-1] == "(") {                  # if previous delimiter was "(" then ...
               spec[++s]=x[1]                        # push species onto both stacks
               branch[++b]=x[1]
               print x[1],x[2]                       # print current species/nbr to stdout
            }
            else
            if (seps[i-1] == ",") {                  # if previous delimiter was "," then ...
               branch[++b]=x[1]                      # push species onto the branch stack
               print x[1],x[2]                       # print current species/nbr to stdout
            }
        }
      }
' input.txt
```

This generates:

```
########### new table
hg38    0.00390111
panTro4 0.00466345
hg38-panTro4    0.0067608
ponAbe2 0.0116062
hg38-ponAbe2    0.00867419
rheMac3 0.00199139
macFas5 0.00136397
rheMac3-macFas5 0.00219754
papAnu2 0.00373049
rheMac3-papAnu2 0.00221139
chlSab2 0.00690005
rheMac3-chlSab2 0.00434788
nasLar1 0.00415921
rhiRox1 0.00361872
nasLar1-rhiRox1 0.0075705
rheMac3-nasLar1 0.0149329
hg38-rheMac3    0.0129667
calJac3 0.025809
saiBol1 0.0245054
calJac3-saiBol1 0.0316131
hg38-calJac3    0.0521649
tarSyr2 0.113368
hg38-tarSyr2    0.00737652
micMur1 0.0695349
otoGar3 0.105996
micMur1-otoGar3 0.0356137
hg38-micMur1    0.00510281
mm10    0.304925
```

Comment: Man, absolutely AMAZING!!!! Thank you so much for this! 
It worked perfectly!!!!
Thank you so much for helping and for all the explanation about the code